# Reading a Text file in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, inheritance, text

First off, I'm a complete beginner.

This might be a stupid question, but here it goes:

I'm currently working on an App than contains Latin texts that the users can view and read. 
I'm using Xcode 4 with the storybord function. 
Theway the app is built: user selects author - then the book - then app shows the text.

I am kind of confused because i need to have various text files, depending on the users choice.

Comment: Where are you wanting to store the files? Will they be inside the database (i.e. core data) or embedded as a resource?

Comment: I was thinking of placing as coredata (onless the other thing is easier to handle

Comment: Even a complete beginner knows what a question is. `I'm thinking of X' is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

As i have done or do usually just embedded the files as resource and by using the below code I read-out the files

in .h file

```
-(NSString *)readFile:(NSString *)fileName;
```

in .m file

```
-(NSString *)readFile:(NSString *)fileName

{
    NSLog(@"readFile");

    NSString *appFile = fileName;    
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appFile])        
    {
        NSError *error= NULL;
        NSString *resultData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: appFile encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error]; 
        if (error == NULL)            
            return resultData;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

May this will help you

Enjoy Coding :)

**EDIT**

What I have done is according to the date change on one button click and also at the time of `viewWillApper` I call the function below

```
-(void)dateAndContentReload
{
    NSLog(@"dateAndContentReload");

    NSLog(@"Appdelegate Date: %@",appDelegate.dateSelected);
    self.currentDate = appDelegate.dateSelected;
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: appDelegate.dateSelected];

    self.navigationItem.title = dateString; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"Myyyy"];
    NSString *dateComp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: appDelegate.dateSelected];
    //NSLog(@"date : %@",dateString);
    NSString *data;
    NSString *path;

    if(![dateComp isEqualToString: @"12012"])
    {
        NSString *size = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f",appDelegate.size]  ; 
        NSLog(@"dateAndContentReload size: %f",appDelegate.size);

        data = @"<html><body><font size='";
        data = [data stringByAppendingString: size];
        data = [data stringByAppendingString: @"'><P>"];

        data = @"Data not Available for Current Date.";

        data = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString:@"<br>"];

        data = [data stringByAppendingString:@"</P></font></body></html>"];
    }
    else
    {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMMd"];
        dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: appDelegate.dateSelected];
        [dateFormatter release];
        NSLog(@"new Format: %@",dateString);

        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: dateString ofType: @"txt"];
        data = nil;
        NSString *size = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f",appDelegate.size]  ; 
        NSLog(@"dateAndContentReload size: %f",appDelegate.size);

        data = @"<html><body><font size='";
        data = [data stringByAppendingString: size];
        data = [data stringByAppendingString: @"'><P>"];

        data = [data stringByAppendingString: [self readFile: path]];

        data = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString:@"<br>"];

        data = [data stringByAppendingString:@"</P></font></body></html>"];
    }

    [self.currentView loadHTMLString: data baseURL: nil];
}
```

Basically I read file and display in `UIWebView` as client request it.

Comment: So where do enter the location of the file ?

Comment: where you want to read it ie on button click or on load or when you want to read the fiel